# How long do untouched cartridges last?

Tags: cartridge

I have an Epson SX215 printer. Can I buy multiple cartridges without being worried about their expiration time? I plan to have around 3 of them, and for me they might suffice for about half a year. Can they go dry in 6 months?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like batteries, ink cartridges normally have an expiration date printed on them - or on the cardboard box they are packaged in. You can expect cartridges to work *at least* until that date, if you don't open the packaging.

Once you open the packaging, you should expect the inks to dry out within 2-6 months depending on brand, weather, and other factors.

Answer (score 0):

Out of protection, the ink will go dry whether in the printing heads of the cartridge or just on the sponge used to spread the ink :( It also depends on the weather conditions (dry/cold/hot...) I can't give an estimation... however 6 months looks big. Maybe you can remove them to protect them somehow?

Comment: Well I don't want to plugin them all. I just want to buy them in bulk. And obviously I can find a cold dry place to store them before they're used.

Comment: Yep so as torbengb said, look at the expiration date and it should be ok

Comment: "All Your Drop Are Belong to Us"  http://www.drdobbs.com/184405157;jsessionid=4SI0IMNFFALHPQE1GHPSKH4ATMY32JVN